# EFCore Tracking with Includes

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following code:

```cs
public class TreatmentJournal
{
    [Key]
    public int JournalId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }     

    
    public List<ProcedureModel> TreatmentProcedures { get; set; } = new();
    
}

public class ProcedureModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProcedureName { get; set; }   
    public decimal ProcedureCost { get; set; }
            
    public List<TreatmentJournal> Visits { get; set; } = new();

}
```

I load treatments as follows:

```cs
TreatmentList = await DataService.GetTreatments(AppState.SelectedPatient.PatientId);
ProceduresMainList = await DataService.GetProcedures();
```

`GetTreatments()` and `GetProcedures()` are as follows:

```cs
public async Task<List<TreatmentJournal>> GetTreatments(int patientid)
{
    List<TreatmentJournal> treatments = new List<TreatmentJournal>();
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        treatments = await context.Treatments
                    .Where(p => p.PatientId == patientid)
                    .Include(p => p.TreatmentProcedures)
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.TreatmentDateTime)
                    .ToListAsync();


    }
    return treatments;
}

public async Task<List<ProcedureModel>> GetProcedures()
{
    List<ProcedureModel> procedureList = new();
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {

        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        try
        {
            procedureList = await context.Procedures.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(d => d.ProcedureName).ToListAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    if (procedureList is null)
        procedureList = new();
    return procedureList;
}
```

and `UpdateTreatmentJournal()`:

```cs
public async Task<bool> UpdateTreatmentJournal(TreatmentJournal item)
{
    int res = 0;
    item.TenantId = _tenantId;
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        try
        {
            
            context.Treatments.Update(item);
            res = await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    if (res >= 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

When I update using the UpdateTreatmentJournal method, I get the following tracking error from EFCore:

> The instance of entity type 'TreatmentJournal' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{JournalId: 14}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I have tried using .NoTracking() when loading Procedures and TreatmentJournal but it does not seem to make a difference. Some places I read that .Include does not use .AsNoTracking(). In order to load the TreatmentJournal entries, .Include is used to load the related Procedures for each TreatmentJournal entry.

Comment: Apparently `_scopeFactory.CreateScope()` creates a singleton scope, which probably also means that you get the same singleton context instance each time. It's very uncommon to create a scope in each method. I think you should re-evaluate the scoping in your application.

Comment: So if that is true, then the dbcontext should be the same throughout the application? Why should then EFCore complain that the entity is being tracked in "another instance"?

Comment: No, *another instance with the key value '{JournalId: 14}' is already being tracked*, i.e. a `TreatmentJournal` instance.

Comment: The first Procedure entry inserts just fine. But if i have two or more Procedures in a TreatmentJournal entry, I get the tracking error. It seems that while updating, efcore encounters the TreatmentJournal entry twice because of two procedures. But since it is the same TreatmentJournal instance, it raises this error. I have no way to circumvent this unless I insert each procedure one by one into the database. Anyone?

Comment: *The first Procedure entry inserts just fine.* Not sure what that means, but what you say now suggests that `ProcedureModel` has a reference property `TreatmentJournal`. What is the exact content of a failing `item` variable? (You could show it as JSON).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having weird issues like this and couldn't figure out why things were being tracked. So I then moved to an approach where all reads were using AsNoTracking. Then when I need to update a record, I would read the record, with tracking, amend its values, then write it back, all within the same update method.

Here is a basic example.

I get 1 order from the DB like so

```cs
    public async ValueTask<Order> SelectOrderByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        return await Orders.FindAsync(id);
    }
```

So no tracking.

Then I make amendments to that Order and want to update it in the DB again, this is my update method.

```cs
    public async ValueTask<Order> UpdateOrderAsync(Order record)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior= QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll;

        var oldOrder = await Orders.FindAsync(record.Id);
        Entry(oldOrder!).CurrentValues.SetValues(record);
        await SaveChangesAsync();

        return record;
    }
```

In this method you can see that I setup the change track to track all, then I read the order from the DB, set its values (which replaces any values which are different in my inbound model) and then save the changes.

Comment: I have tried this approach as well. It's the same thing. The tracking error is not coming from elsewhere, it's coming from the very list of procedures that I am saving. So tracking starts when I run the update statement.